# rostopic not showing data electric

Tags: wireless, master, rosmaster, publisher, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two laptops running Ubuntu lucid and ROS electric. I have written three publishers in roscpp that are publishing input data to rostopics.

When running on one computer, I am able to see the topics and echo them to see the data being published.

For the second computer, I have set the ROS_MASTER_URI to the IP of the first computer, and when doing a rostopic list I am able to see the topics from the first computer. But when I rostopic echo, I do not see any of   the data that is visible on the first computer.

I can ping back and forth, ssh and copy files, and I see the topic list change correctly as I start and kill my publishers. I do not know what the issue is. My ros_master_uri is set correctly, and the publishers are giving data to the topic. It just doesnt come through the wireless.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34514/rostopic-not-showing-data-electric/) by [Blstinne](https://answers.ros.org/users/2371/blstinne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that you don't have ROS_IP set correctly. A resolvable ROS_IP is required for the rostopic echo node to be fully connected with your publisher. You should be able to verify that the connection exists using rxgraph. You should also set ROS_IP on both machines.

You can read more about setting up your network [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup).

You can read more about ROS_IP [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_IP.2BAC8-ROS_HOSTNAME).

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1